# CKEditor: Created (copied from Moono) a new skin, missing skin.js file

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am starting to learn how to build a CKEditor skin. I copied the moono directory and created my own but I get the following error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://local-sandbox/js/ckeditor/skins/customskin/skin.js?t=E1PE"
```

I can't seem to find this file anywhere, and it wasn't in the moono directory. Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually **skin.js** must be in mono directory, and this file is **mandatory**.

File can be found in CKEditor path: [ckeditor-dev/skins/moono/skin.js](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/skins/moono/skin.js).

It's well documented so you'll find a lot of explanations there.

For more info, go to [CKEditor skin introduction](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/skin_sdk_intro)

Comment: Mandatory? Then why does no ckeditor 4.x Download include this file?

Comment: @mondjunge for the default skin, the CKEditor builder does an optimization and inlines javascript logic into `ckeditor.js` - that's why you don't see this file in a built package.

Comment: makes sense. But there seems to be a flaw: Our webserver logs 404 messages for skin.js, that seem to come from the ckeditor code. We created the file to get rid of those error messages for server performance (rendering error pages that nobody sees is not performace wise)